# Запись в файл, в обратном порядке

Tags: файлы, c++

Есть один текстовый файл с цифрами через пробел, нужно создать второй файл и записать эти цифры в обратом порядке. Как это сделать? У меня есть идея, что можно при записи в цикле постоянно переходить в начало файла, но как перейти в начало? Используя библиотеку <fstream>.

Файл я создаю таким способом:

```
ifstream file1;
ofstream file2;
file1.open( "f1.txt" );
file2.open("f2.txt");
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не нужно инвертировать вывод путем манипуляций с курсором файла - перейдите на уровень выше. Вы считываете цифры в массив? Тогда выводите их в файл в обратном порядке, обращаясь к самому массиву в обратном порядке: digits[n-1], digits[n-2], ...
А если у вас там одна строка и только беззнаковые числа из одной цифры, то проще будет считать строку, инвертировать ее и записать.

Comment: "проще будет считать строку, инвертировать ее и записать." как это сделать?

Comment: считываю не в массив, т.к кол-во цифр в первом фаиле не известно ( цифры там целые, без дробей ), я думал сделать так: записать одну цифру в переменную, потом с этой переменной записать во второй файл, потом с первого фаила снова записать цифру в туже переменную ( заменив старую )

Answer (score 4):

1. Если память не ограничена, выделить с заведомо достаточным размером массив и считать весь файл в буфер, а затем выводить в файл в обратном порядке. Вместо массива можно использовать стек.
2. Если память ограничена, выделить подходящий буфер, переместить указатель файла в конец минус размер буфера, считать в буфер, найти первый перевод строки, распарсить и вывести в файл в обратном порядке. Затем передвинуть указатель назад на два буфера.

Answer (score 2):

В NT: спроецировать файловую секцию, сортировать данные в этой проекции и зафлушить её обратно в файл. Стопяцот обращений к ядру для записи в файл каждого символа или строки просто глупо.

Answer (score 0):

Правило стека: первый вошел последний вышел вполне подходит для решения этой задачи.

Comment: Не вполне понятно, что вы предлагаете. Поместить весь файл в стек?

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?